# Partition method for ksmall in an unsorted array returning an out of bound exception

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Trying to figure out how to understand how to find the kth smallest number in an unsorted array. I've heard that job interviews are notorious for using this, and I'm trying to get a strong grasp of it. Not sure where I'm hitting this exception, nor if my logic is even sound. Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
public class KthSmallest {

private static void swap(int[] theArray, int i, int j) {
    int temp = theArray[i];
    theArray[i] = theArray[j];
    theArray[j] = temp;
}

private static int partition(int[] theArray, int first, int last) {



    int p = theArray[first]; 
    int lastS1 = first + 1;
    int lastS2 = last;

    while (lastS1 < lastS2) {

        while (theArray[lastS1] < theArray[p] && lastS1 < last) {
            lastS1++;

            while (theArray[lastS2] > theArray[p] && theArray[lastS2] >= first) {
                lastS2--;

                if (lastS1 < lastS2) {
                    swap(theArray, lastS1, lastS2);
                }
            }
        }


        swap(theArray, lastS1, lastS2);

    }

    return lastS1;// the index of the pivot element
}
}
```

Comment: I dont think your partition code is correct. The two while loops inside the outer while loop have to be separated. In partition basically you have to advance low, high pointers separately.

Comment: @SomeDude I placed my inner-while outside of that one, but it isn't really changing anything. My exception is at the second while loop... Not sure of the logic